# set calendar object hour to 0

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp

this is my code

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    Timestamp start = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
```

but the timestamp result is for instance = 2014-09-30 02:00:00.0 I´m not able to set the hours to 0.

Any suggestions.

Comment: And how is the result `"2014-09-30 02:00:00.0"` constructed? Most likely by a formatter which uses a different timezone (not UTC).

Comment: http://ideone.com/tQZIlW

Comment: Set the Hour of day to 22 and DAY_OF_MONTH to DAY_OF_MONTH -1

Comment: I recommend you to use the joda-time library for this kind of issue: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ this way you can easily create the wished instance by calling DateTime yourDateTime = DateTime.now().withSecondOfMinute(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withHourOfDay(0); To retrieve your wished Calendar object you can check this method in joda time Calendar: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toCalendar(java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 2):

Once you call `Calendar.getTime()` you get a `Date` object which is an instant in time which has **no timezone info**.

When you want to print or present this instance, the formatter will use the default time zone if not explicitly specified, which in your case is not UTC but maybe CET.

When you convert this instant to a `String`, you also have to tell in which timezone you want it to present. You have to specify UTC timezone there as well.

For example if using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can use its [`setTimeZone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-) method.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

System.out.println(sdf.format(start));
```

Also if your result is from your database, you have to use a `timestamp` SQL type without timezone or with the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I guest icza is right.

To be sure, try this :

```
Timestamp start = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
System.out.println(start.getTimezoneOffset());
```